# Extracting chromosome coordinates from a CSV file using R

Tags: r

I am trying to extract genome locations in R from a text file. I'm a little lost and need some advice. The data output when I the read.csv file looks like this:

3                                                                        chr1\t34130107\t34134640  NA  NA
4                                                                        chr1\t36070190\t36074608  NA  NA
5                                                                        chr1\t36111164\t36118698  NA  NA
6                                                                        chr1\t37039139\t37045411  NA  NA
7                                                                       chr1\t72260528\t72261272  NA  NA

ps, there is a gap between the first number and the "chr*"

I welcome your responses!

Comment: It looks like this is tab delimited. Did you try `read.delim`?

Comment: What it looks to us is not what it looks to you. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Also, instead of the `read.csv` output, you could just give us the contents of the raw file.

Comment: Ananda - I will try read.delim, thank you

Comment: flodel-is there away to upload the raw content to display? many thanks